# Getting image to appear below text on mobile device

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys i have an image side by sdie with some text and i am trying to get it to appear below the text on a mobile device but right now its appearing above it, I'm using bootstrap 3.

html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 ">
    <div class="about-img"><img src="img/about.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="about-text">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <hr>
      <p>Bryggeriet är en restaurang, sportbar och nattklubb som ligger mitt på Avenyn i Göteborg. Sedan vi öppnade portarna 1993 har vi varit ett självklart val för alla som vill äta riktigt god mat, ta en trevlig lunch, följa sitt favoritlag i Sportbaren, komma förbi på en after work eller dansa helgnatten lång. Eller om man bara vill beställa någonting gott att dricka i en avslappnad och gemytlig miljö.</p>
      <p>Hos oss kan och bör du förvänta dig mat som är en fröjd för både ögat och magen. Här står maten i fokus och vi tillagar alla våra rätter från grunden. Det betyder att du får fräsch mat som tillagas när du beställer den, gjord på råvaror av högsta kvalitet. Vi tar inga genvägar, utan serverar endast sådant som vi själva skulle uppskatta att få på tallriken..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

}
```

I have tried to float the element and then use clear:both but i cant seem to get anything to work to make the image appear at the bottom od the div below all the text.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following bootstrap push and pull classes on medium and up screens;

```
col-md-pull-6, col-md-push-6
```

This will reorganise the flow of content - for example:  https://jsfiddle.net/hfwr6n8z/2/

You should also restructure your HTML, and place the image wrapper div last in the DOM, so it is displayed last on small screens.